# Do I need to redraw all objects on a canvas every frame?

Tags: android, canvas, game-loop

I am setting up a game loop.  The loop is set to update at 50 FPS.  Currently the only action the app does is draw screen coordinates on response to touch events.  Originally I set up the draw function to only draw new touch events. This caused the text to blink.  Multiple touch events blink at different times, which leads me to think that Canvas uses multiple pages behind the scenes.  In an effort to get around this I made a list of every touch event that happened and on every draw call I redraw the entire list.

Please correct me if I am wrong, the lockCanvas()/unlockCanvasAndPost() calls are in essence a backbuffer swap. Reading the documentation on locking and unlocking it sounds like it is necessary to redraw the entire scene between calls unless you use lockCanvas(Rect dirty). In this case the dirty rect area needs to be redraw while the outside area is preserved.

> The content of the Surface is never preserved between unlockCanvas()
>   and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area
>   must be written. The only exception to this rule is when a dirty
>   rectangle is specified, in which case, non-dirty pixels will be
>   preserved.

I know it sounds like I've answered my own question, but according to the documentation the Surface is never preserved between calls. However this does not explain the behavior of my first implementation, which was I would tap the screen and the text would start blinking. Since I only drew the text one time, this would mean that the blinking is from swapping to the "backbuffer" which didn't get the drawText() call, and the original Surface which did not get destroyed but perhaps it is to be considered unreliable.

So, the question: Do I need to redraw all objects on each draw call? And if so, do I need to "clear" the canvas, or at the least redraw the background image also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, unless you're doing a dirty redraw where you define the region that you are redrawing, every point on your canvas gets destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there some better documentation as to how this whole process works?  I would think that if the Surface was destroyed between calls that I would have a blip rather than blinking text when there has only been one drawText() call. So either the Surface does get destroyed but is recreated at the same memory location, that way the 'dirty' memory looks like nothings changed; or, the Surface isn't destroyed, but 'should' be considered unreliable, perhaps because some other function might change it between lock/unlock calls. It would be nice to know exactly how this works.

Comment: I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to do, but in all my manual canvas drawing apps I've never seen any flickering. I believe the double buffering is handled automatically (I certainly have never had to manage it manually).  Every time invalidate is called the onDraw callback is invoked and the canvas redraws. I can't say what the Surface *actually does... I've never looked at the underlying code.

Comment: At this point I am only trying to get a better understanding of what was happening. Now I am getting flicker free animation by clearing the canvas and redrawing everything. I was just curious as to why I got the flicker from a single draw call.  My original assumption was that the canvas was persistent, so in theory locking/unlocking I was dealing with the same Surface. This is not the case, so locking/unlocking brings up a different Surface. This is what I have gathered so far. I was hoping to find better documentation on this behavior besides my own observations.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: Passing a dirtyRect will destroy performance as it has to copy the contents from the previous  buffer. Sure wish there was a way to turn off double buffering..